# I need to remove the duplicates and sum the total with objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reduce

So, far I have been able to remove the duplicates, but I don't know how to sum the
Total_Quantity. Is there a way I can just sum the Total_Quantity within the reduced method? Thank you in advance.

```
const test = [
        {
            Item_Name: "Washing Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 2,
        },
        {
            Item_Name: "Washing Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 2,
        },
        {
            Item_Name: "Washing Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 2,
        },
        {
            Item_Name: "Washing Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 2,
        },
        {
            Item_Name: "Dryer Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 5,
        },
        {
            Item_Name: "Dryer Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 5,
        },
        {
            Item_Name: "Dryer Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 5,
        },
        {
            Item_Name: "Dryer Machine",
            Total_Quantity: 5,
        },
    ];

    const dup = [
                ...test.reduce(
                    (map, obj) => map.set(obj.Item_Name, obj),
                    new Map()
                ).values(),
            ];
    
    console.log(dup)
```

**The code should look like this**

```
 const dup = [
    {
        Item_Name: "Washing Machine",
        Total_Quantity: 8,
    },

    {
        Item_Name: "Dryer Machine",
        Total_Quantity: 20,
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const test = 
  [ { Item_Name: 'Washing Machine', Total_Quantity: 2 } 
  , { Item_Name: 'Washing Machine', Total_Quantity: 2 } 
  , { Item_Name: 'Washing Machine', Total_Quantity: 2 } 
  , { Item_Name: 'Washing Machine', Total_Quantity: 2 } 
  , { Item_Name: 'Dryer Machine',   Total_Quantity: 5 } 
  , { Item_Name: 'Dryer Machine',   Total_Quantity: 5 } 
  , { Item_Name: 'Dryer Machine',   Total_Quantity: 5 } 
  , { Item_Name: 'Dryer Machine',   Total_Quantity: 5 } 
  ] 
const sum = Object.entries(test.reduce((a,{Item_Name, Total_Quantity})=>
  {
  a[Item_Name] = (a[Item_Name] ?? 0) + Total_Quantity
  return a
  },{})).map(([Item_Name, Total_Quantity])=>({Item_Name, Total_Quantity}))

console.log ( sum )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```